# how to create a hierarchy of locations

Tags: c#

Let's say there is a table in which data like country, city, subcity, etc. is mixed. Example:

```
Name | id | parent_id
1) united kingdom | 1 | 0;
2) london | 2 | 1;
3) south london | 3 | 2;
```

I get data from the table and need to create a URL for each city, for example, for south London:

```
/united-kingdom/london/south-london
```

how to create such a hierarchy from such incoming data?

```
var geoSolution = await _geoService.GetGeoChildren(selectedCountry, culture, cancellationToken);   
foreach (var geo in geoSolution.Value ?? Enumerable.Empty<Geo>())
{
    if (geo.ParentId == null) continue; 
    sitemapList.Add(new SitemapHtml(geo.GeoName ?? string.Empty, GetPrefix(geo.Name ?? string.Empty, product ?? ""))
    {
        Links = await GetSitemapLinksForGeo(urlSections, geo, cancellationToken, true)
    });
}

return sitemapList.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

geoSolution return me list of those objects, each of them have the id and parentId, if its country => parentId == null

Comment: Look up "recursion".

Comment: Your code snippet is terrible to understand. A [mcve] would have been great here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you start with this input data:

```
var table = new[]
{
    new { Name = "united kingdom", Id = 1, ParentId = 0 },
    new { Name = "london", Id = 2, ParentId = 1 },
    new { Name = "south london", Id = 3, ParentId = 2 },
    new { Name = "kensington", Id = 4, ParentId = 2 },
    new { Name = "cardiff", Id = 5, ParentId = 1 },
    new { Name = "caerphilly", Id = 6, ParentId = 5 },
};
```

Then you can easily turn this into a set of URLs like this:

```
var lookup = table.ToLookup(x => x.ParentId);

IEnumerable<string> GetUrls(int parentId) =>
    from child in lookup[parentId]
    orderby child.Name
    from suburl in GetUrls(child.Id).DefaultIfEmpty("")
    select $"/{child.Name.Replace(" ", "-") + suburl}";

var urls = GetUrls(0).ToList();
```

That then produces:

```
/united-kingdom/cardiff/caerphilly
/united-kingdom/london/kensington
/united-kingdom/london/south-london
```

If you need to keep track of the id from each city then this does that:

```
IEnumerable<(int id, string url)> GetUrls(int parentId) =>
    from child in lookup[parentId]
    orderby child.Name
    from suburl in GetUrls(child.Id).DefaultIfEmpty((id: -1, url: ""))
    select
    (
        suburl.id == -1 ? child.Id : suburl.id,
        $"/{child.Name.Replace(" ", "-") + suburl.url}"
    );
```

That gives:

[image: urls]